# Google sheets script or formula to add page numbers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I use a Google sheet to populate and print a form with a list attached. I want to add page numbers starting on page 3. I don't want to use the built in page number (footer) function because it changes the margins of my static form on pages 1-2. Is there a script or function that can identify the page breaks and insert page numbers starting on page 3?

Comment: May I try to clarify, please correct me if I am wrong. You have a Google sheet; the sheet contains a form (NOT a Google Form) and the contents of the form are populated from the sheet. When you print the form (over 2 pages) in Google Sheets it is OK; but when you print an accompanying list, you would want the page numbers to start at #3 so that they follow on from the form, and you want to use a different footer to keep consistency of the form's margins. All these things, you would like to wrap up into a single script.

Comment: Are you printing to a printer (onto paper) or to a PDF?

Comment: Paper. Thanks! - josh

Comment: Tedinoz: Yes. You understand correctly.  - j